# How to build UWP app bundle concurrently for different processor architectures

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to build separate architectures (arm, x86, x64) on separate machines and then bundle them together. I would like to do this to speed up build process (to cut build time in 3). I can easily run build on separate machines, but I have no idea how to combine these files into single bundle.

Comment: Hi, this is not recommended. When Visual Studio build packages, it will sequentially generate the packages of the platform you selected and combine them together. The combined package will merge some of the same content, such as certificates and Manifest files. If packaged separately, subsequent merges will be more troublesome.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT there is no way to speedup this process? Generating package takes ages, especially native code generation. For instance compile sources and then just merge bundles using separate tool.

Comment: Hi, at present, packaging applications through Visual Studio is the recommended method.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I am packaging apps in ADO, so Visual Studio is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since packages are just zip files, you can change them to `.zip` and combine the content.